# Add QGraphicsView on form from another class

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qmainwindow

I have a **MainWindow** class and **Another** class. **Another** class has  method *createView* that create new **QGraphicsView**. This method I call from **MainWindow** and I also want to layout this view on my form. It looks like:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)) {
       ...
       AnotherClass object(this);
       object.createView();
       ...
}
...
void AnotherClass::createView() {
       QGraphicsView *gv= new QGraphicsView(mainWindow); // mainWindow - pointer to MainWindow object
       gv->show();
}
```

But it doesn't work so good... actually it does't work at all. And yes, I save pointer on MainWindow object in my **Another** class as mainWindow, that I take from **Another** class constructor.
If use

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)) {
       ...
       QGraphicsView *gv= new QGraphicsView(this); 
       gv->show();
       ...
}
```

It will work fine, but this solution doesn't satisfied me.

Comment: Code as posted in first example simply won't compile - is object created on the heap or on the stack?

Comment: Oh, thnx. My mistake was in creating variable on stack

Comment: These two pieces of code should work equally. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in creating variable on stack.